# Some questions about split_train_test() function

Tags: linear-regression, training-data

I am currently trying to use Python's linearregression() model to describe  the relationship between two variables X and Y. Given a dataset with 8 columns and 1000 rows, I want to split this dataset into training and test sets using split_train_test.

**My question:** I wonder what is the difference between train_test_split(dataset, test_size, random_test = int) vs train_test_split(dataset, test_size).Also, does the 2nd one (without setting random_test=int) give me a different test set and training set each time I re-run my program? Also, does the 1st one give me the same test set and training set every time I re-run my program? What is the difference between setting random_test=42 vs random_test=43, for example?

Comment: What is the python library you use, is it scikit-learn?

Comment: @Charles: yes!! I used sklearn.model_selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python scikit-learn train_test_split will split your input data into two sets i) train and ii) test. It has argument random_state which allows you to split data randomly.

If the argument is not mentioned it will classify the data in a stratified manner which will give you the same split for the same dataset.

Assume you want a random split the data so that you could measure the performance of your regression on the same data with different splits. you can use random_state to achieve it. Each random state will give you pseudo-random split of your initial data. In order to keep track of performance and reproduce it later on the same data you will use the random_state argument with value used before.

It is useful for `cross validation` technique in machine learning.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your great answer! I thought without random_state, a different split would be generated every time I re-run the program;p So, if I set random_state= 42, what does this *REALLY* mean? Also, could you elaborate, in code language, how we could keep track of performance to compare if we generate a different test and train set every time I re-run the program?

Comment: I tried setting random_state = 42, and ran my program 3 times. I got the same RMSE every single times(?!). I wonder how could the test and training set be random if this is the case;p Note that my test size/validation size = 1/4, and I only have around ~1500 rows of data

Comment: It is not random as you keep the random state of the split remains same. If you want different random split, try using a different value to the random state . If you keep on the same random_state, you will get the same result, which is the sole purpose of the `option random_state` in `train_test_split`

Comment: Then what is the difference with and without random_state, if I still cannot generate different splits even when turning on the option random_state?

Comment: Lets say we have only a less number of dataset which get a unique split into train and test set. Now we need a different set of train and test set for training your kernel, you can use a different random_state in train_test_split to generate a different combination train and test with the same set(new set in terms of kernel). Now it would be hard to keep track of this train and test sets, as you may need in future for re-evaluation. Thus it is useful.

Comment: Do you know a built-in code to keep track of all the test and train sets that I have used, as well as the corresponding RMSE, if each time I generate a different split?

Comment: No I am not sure of it.